# adding filters to an analysis in obiee

Tags: oracle, report, oracle12c, business-intelligence, obiee

I am using Oracle Business Intelligence. For my analysis, I want to add a filter to it so that user can type in textfield and then the data related to input in textfield is displayed. Table prompts only suggest drop-down list, while column prompts do what I want but they appear before I see the analysis. I want to filter when I have the analysis on the screen.

While we did that kind of work in BI publisher using data models and reports, it was possible to run the report and give the parameters to get the desired data. How can I do this in the analysis? Is there something similar to parameters or list of values that are in BI Publisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. That's normal prompt functionality. Just click on the column prompt options and choose to display the prompt as a free text field and allow user to enter their own values instead of choosing from the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Chris, but I tried displaying column prompt as a text field. The problem is that the prompt appears before I see the analysis. For example, I want, first, to look at a data, let's say table with hundreds rows, and after that I want to enter some value to filter out my desired record. I hope I could make it  clear

Comment: Then you are just using the wrong prompt. You must not use a prompt IN the analysis. You must use a dashboard prompt! The in-line prompts which are part of the analysis are way too restrictive and pretty much useless.

Comment: Ah, I see. That was what I was looking for. I wanted to know whether it is possible or not. I hoped that there is a way to do it in the analysis. Thank you for your help, Chris

Comment: No..an analysis is a not a good vehicle to use with prompts in-line - so attached to the analysis itself. They are much more reusable and flexible when combined with real dashboard prompts